# Compare data with different scale with clustered column chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this data that I'd like to visually compare:

[image]

If I pick a clustered column chart this is what I get. As you can see, the second column has a different scale so I need to use a separate axis:

[image]

However, here's what I get if I right click the data of the second column and use a secondary axis:

[image]

My questions:

1) How do I make the axes alligned horizontally at zero? The second axis zero is currently at around -200 of the first one: I'd like them to be alligned.

2) How do I make the columns not overlapping? I'd like them like in the first graph, one near the other: is it possible?

Comment: Please paste some sample data into a code block so it can be copied and pasted into a file.

Comment: For Q1, you may modify the minimum value for the first vertical axis to let 0 of the 2 vertical axes on a horizontal line as possible.